# Basic post request for users using express (React)

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs, express

I am having serious issues trying to solve this issue and any help would be appreciated greatly

So all I am trying to do is a simple register activity for users where I will be able to sign them up to the site.

I am using mssql, and express.

This is My Register.js. All I want is for the details input into the buttons to be passed through to the json body so it can then be used in my server.js.

Register.js

```
class AddUsers extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { users: [] };
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = { email: this.ref.email, password: this.ref.password };
    // const data = { name: "", password: "" };

    fetch("/admin-Add-Users", {
      method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log("Success:", data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.users);
    return (
      <div>
        <LoginForm></LoginForm>

        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="email" ref="email" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="password" ref="password" />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my server.js (config file is working). Here all I want is for the data previously added to be stored in my database (SQL server).

```
app.post("/admin-Add-Users", function(req, res) {

  const { password, email } = req.body;

  var request = new sql.Request();

 // query to the database and get the records
    request.query( "insert into Login (email, password) values ('"+email+"','"+password+"')", function(err, recordset) {
      if (err) console.log(err);

  });
  res.send({ message: "Success" });
});
```

I have no idea how to get the data from the inputs to just be stored through my server.js. Please any help or examples are appreciated. I am new to react so please explain like I am five years old.

Error I am now receiving

```
Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `isPropagationStopped` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to avoid use `refs` in react unless you have a good reason to use them (some things like animations need to be controlled imperatively).

The React way is to do things declaratively with state, so changing an input updates the associated state field, and then the `onSubmit` function takes the values from state.  Something like this:

```
class AddUsers extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { users: [], email: '', password: '' };
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password };

    fetch("/admin-Add-Users", {
      method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log("Success:", data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.users);
    return (
      <div>
        <LoginForm></LoginForm>

        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={e => 
               this.setState({email: e.target.value})} />
          <input type="text" placeholder="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={e => 
              this.setState({password: e.target.value})} />
          <input type="submit" onPress={this.onSubmit} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have given that a go but when data is added it seemed to do nothing. The console displays nothing and the text input simply appear blank again.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include adding the values to the input based on state, I edited my answer to show this.  Add the values and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you I will try now! So the server.js should all be working as well ?

Comment: This will no longer allow text inputs into the inputs. When typed into the inputs only display "[object Object]". This is no matter what key is pressed.

Comment: I guess I mistyped, didn't notice you were using actual DOM input elements.  In that case you need to extract the value from the event.  I edited my answer to explain better.  Look at how I changed the onChange function of the inputs to use the event's value

Comment: OKay that makes sense. However It is still not working.

Comment: You should add a console.log into your onChange functions then to see where the error is, make sure the e.target.value is what you expect.

Comment: I am not sure how I would implement these into the ones I currently have

Comment: ``` ReferenceError: email is not defined ``` from my server.js file

Comment: Are you using bodyParser for express to be able to access the body?

Comment: I don't believe so. How would I implement this ??

Comment: I answered your initial question, sorry, but I cannot walk you through correctly setting up an entire application in stack overflow comments.  Try reading some of the express docs: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: Ok no worries. is body parser needed?

Comment: Yes if you want to parse the body of a POST, PUT, etc request, which is what you are trying to do.  I would do some research into setting up a basic express app, pretty much all tutorials will explain it.